# Typescript : type inference for Objects inside an array

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I've been struggling for several days trying to accomplish some Typescript proper inference in order to achieve type validation on the data structure provided to one of my Class constructors.

Essentially my constructor receives an array containing a list of objects that contain a declaration of a (sort of) plugin and a "custom configuration" for the plugin, each one.

I need Typescript to ensure the provided `customConfig` matches the types on the `defaultConfig`, however, I had no luck, not even getting close to it.

The several attempts I've made become really messy and nonsensical, so I will attach a simple representation of the code that I hope helps to represent the idea :

I hope somebody can provide some light

```js
type Entry = {
    extension: {
        defaultConfig: Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
        install: any
        uninstall: any
    },
    customConfig: Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
}


function initExtensions<I extends Entry[]>(a: I): void { /* ... */ }


initExtensions([
    {
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { foo: true },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { foo: true } // <-- SHOULD BE OK
    },
    {
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { bar: 123 },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { bar: true }  // <-- Should complain as should be a NUMBER
    },
])
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope, the below solution achieves *almost* what you are looking for.

```
// keeping defaultConfig and customConfig as seperate generics makes TS inference more granular
type EntryRaw<C extends {}, U extends {}> = {
    extension: {
        defaultConfig: C
        install: any
        uninstall: any
    },
    customConfig: U
}

// checks if configs are equal types wise
type ValidEntry<E extends EntryRaw<{}, {}>> = E extends EntryRaw<infer C, infer U> ? C extends U ? U extends C ? E : never : never : never


type ValidEntries<ES extends EntryRaw<{}, {}>[]> =
    ES extends [] ? ES : // recursion condition
    ES extends [infer E, ...infer R] ? // destruct
    E extends EntryRaw<{}, {}> ? // auxiliary check to allow ValidEntry check
    R extends EntryRaw<{}, {}>[] ? // auxiliary check to allow recursive 'call'
    E extends ValidEntry<E> ?
        [E, ...ValidEntries<R>] : // entry ok, recursive 'call'
        // some hacky error reporting
        [{ __INCOMPATABLE_CONFIG__: [E['extension']['defaultConfig'], 'vs', E['customConfig']] } & Omit<E, 'customConfig'>, ...ValidEntries<R>] 
            : never  : never  : never


// I have been not able to make TS happy with single array argument 
function initExtensions<ES extends EntryRaw<{}, {}>[]>(...es: ValidEntries<ES>): void {  
 }

initExtensions(
    {
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { foo: true },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { foo: true } // <-- SHOULD BE OK
    },
    {
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { bar: 123 },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { bar: true }  // <-- Should complain as should be a NUMBER
    },
)
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=8&pln=23&pc=145#code/PTAEGsFNIBwSwHYHNQBNIDMCGBXANgC4DCA9ghnClgqqAMY4DOBJAtqeZaFo6I7JABOWApFBJICIXDq9WWKLwAqAZVCIMQyXTGsSgsUmEJ8WQQCgCATxhiAoggKCrAJSwB3ADxFQkAB6iNLwA3gC+ADSgAKq+AZKoIaEAfKAAvKDB5qDZsYGMcGQAXBlZOWXo2PjEZBRIxUSlZdmIzFh4eMXUVo1NOAgtBG0d3AjdZRE9DMxsHLXFUeah5uYg9AAWkHTgvHAY9DWUvGZikACOOG2g1ra87nD8ljZiAGptcKgOTlaedrnxvJ9nG4vGFImEkil0r9-IEEqBAa4PJ4NEJQERIijBNEUgB+NF-ILRUB4mIw-74vG-YpSABuqOpkDpWIZTOWj1soFeeHegLgkEYPzUZMJCOBnlBGWSAG0ALqQnp2IVxQmy4nwtTFVYGBiCfJkfY0OAEAoIBVK2G8KWY+GRAB09utLhlatW6GYghwdAICoJcNFSIl4JdYFwfjg3LMVnWm3AVxI3HaJHcnLeH0czmjWx6Ll9APTiJBEUlSVVeNWofDcEjmdjLATeCToG1OF1cDpoAA5HQhh2fcK4VyefmfriemUpXY7fbB2mnHyBS4ks7NWBJF9QCRwJFm63212e2OcqtGGwxGssFso0JBPom7B9MbkIfslLgqAAPrvgCSADkiAB5ABZAAFABBJRQIAIQAGTsd8AJ-AAxL8AHFP2KCcpQ7YU9QQDsZSwipcEIWZKHwyIOxpRgO0iOwsKmFh2AOJB8OdUJQAAMlAf9WCNH4KIYmZmI7JIp1tGdeX5TxF2dZ8mhZVFQAUrElNAWkhDZVYv1Ac92wAI2gBA1JIAhuD0vAxDreQoFAVQdKwGAYCjO4CDWPhECQCzuEEYQozMJAcFYNdQHMDA+i9E11H6Ag7GVXCBUVXN4XzMVA2lOUAAp7Vtfligk9N50FJIAEpihpEh3gybIsiWcxECNWK8hNRgMp6TImhyHCTWKdqOqaIiqlIuoqowEgSGKJwcDECY+qaAYhmKDLirSFJgmAAAqUBstAdawBm2acj6eb2kW5bUlWjatvtHa9vCOT9o6wSmM4Ya31G8arg9abQFWTwAFo-tAFQAAl-yiaCABFQEg35-wAaR6B6SlmrqimRg7sgGkjmJ60A9LMYoAEYACYAGZQCR2bjuGJaVoyS7tt2im7ox7IjoQVoTtAWnzvpzbGdu+6Wb6p6htx-HBAmr6KeyX6AaBtYSHwWg6DYGA8CwRBuF4RhFeVvGxCwUAfyiQCYZcRG7uK8wgA)

Comment: Your solution seems to partially work. However, the element that fails validation is the `extension`  one instead of the `customConfig`  ... I've been trying to make it validate in the other way, but I got no success. Any idea?

Comment: Updated to better pin down the issue and put the emphasis on `customConfig`.

Comment: Simply amazing! I will try to study your types and see if I can figure out, how you made this work, in order to adapt it to my real scenario. So many thanks. One final question what is the "vs" you have in the  ValidEntries type?

Comment: The `vs` is totally optional. It meant _expected_ *versus* _provided_; the whole `__INCOMPATABLE_CONFIG__ ` is kind of a hack to report the mismatch. You probably could change it to:  `{ __INCOMPATABLE_CUSTOM_CONFIG__:  E['customConfig'] } ` or remove altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do exactly what you are looking for because TypeScript doesn't support existential types. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466

However, you can create a small wrapper around each of your entries if you just want to validate that it's correct. The wrapper will allow TypeScript to infer the type on each entry in your

```
type Entry<T, C extends T> = {
    extension: {
        defaultConfig: T
        install: any
        uninstall: any
    },
    customConfig: C
}

function asEntry<T, C extends T>(entry: Entry<T, C>) { return entry };

function initExtensions(entries: Entry<any, any>[]): void { /* ... */ }

initExtensions([
    asEntry({
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { foo: true },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { foo: true } // <-- OK
    }),
    asEntry({
        extension: {
            defaultConfig: { bar: 123 },
            install: () => {/* ... */ },
            uninstall: () => {/* ... */ },
        },
        customConfig: { bar: true }  // <-- ERROR
    })
])
```

Comment: I'm aware of the approach you are proposing. but I'm pretty sure I achieved what I'm looking for, some time ago.  Unfortunately, I've not been able to remember where in order to check the applied solution.

Comment: If you find it, post it. I haven't seen a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The method Todd Skelton demonstrates in his answer is the only boilerplate-free solution I know of as well. The problem is that every entry in your input array is of a different type (although extending `Entry`), that needs to be distinctly represented in your generic function signature in order to be correctly type checked. Since there is currently no way to specify a function with a `n` number of template parameters, you'll end up with abominations like this:

```
type Entry<C> = {
    extension: { defaultConfig: C };
    customConfig: Partial<C>;
    install: any;
    uninstall: any;
};

type E<C> = Entry<C>;
function initExtensions<C1,C2,C3,C4,C5>(entries: [E<C1>,E<C2>,E<C3>,E<C4>,E<C5>]): void; 
function initExtensions<C1,C2,C3,C4>(entries: [E<C1>,E<C2>,E<C3>,E<C4>]): void; 
function initExtensions<C1,C2,C3>(entries: [E<C1>,E<C2>,E<C3>]): void; 
function initExtensions<C1,C2>(entries: [E<C1>,E<C2>]): void; 
function initExtensions<C1>(entries: [E<C1>]):void; 
function initExtensions(entries:E<any>[]): void {
    // Initialize your extensions here
}
```

Which in fact works the way you wish up to 5 entries, by representing the input not as an array of one type but as a tuple of different lengths filled with unique types. This might look ugly and weird, but this is in fact how libraries like [lodash type their variadic functions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7bff69b4c447c97af08a88591f0e84941c8f5c76/types/lodash/fp.d.ts#L355) so it's a bit of a necessary evil.

There is nothing stopping you from generating up to 50 variances of this signature of course: it's there for type checking only and is not reflected in your final output. Either that, or pass the configuration objects one by one:

```
function initExtension<C>(entry: Entry<C>): void {
    // Initialize one extension here
}

initExtension({
    extension: { defaultConfig: { foo: true } },
    customConfig: { foo: true },
    install: () => null,
    uninstall: () => null,
});
```

Which is a mere alternative to Todds approach.